# Visual Studio 2012 Test results font

Tags: visual-studio-2012

How do I change the font in VS2012's test results window ?
I'm guessing it's somewhere under `Environment` -> `Fonts and Colors` but there's just too many options there. Here's an image for clarification: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is an awful bug that makes the already unusable test explorer even more unusable. There is a workaround, and that is to set `Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Environment Font` which will change the font in the test explorer window. But this changes everything too.